# Error on inflating layout with navigation

Tags: android, android-layout

When i inflate my layout with navigation drawer there is a error on inflating the layout.what is the problem in this layout.Please help me if someone can.
I am aded navigation_view in between drawer_layout but it cannot work and error on inflating layout

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.techweblearn.musicplayer.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

<include layout="@layout/activity_main_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**activity_main_view.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        style="@style/MyAppTheme"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/black" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/appBar"
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>




<RelativeLayout
    android:elevation="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/design_bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="50dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

    <fragment android:name="com.techweblearn.musicplayer.BottomPlayer"

        android:id="@+id/bottom_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Log**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.techweblearn.musicplayer, PID: 17999
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.techweblearn.musicplayer/com.techweblearn.musicplayer.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                           Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                                           Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                              at com.techweblearn.musicplayer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:116)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                           Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
                                                                              at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:190)
                                                                              at android.content.res.Resources.getColorStateList(Resources.java:992)
                                                                              at android.content.Context.getColorStateList(Context.java:542)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(AppCompatResources.java:65)
                                                                              at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.createDefaultColorStateList(NavigationView.java:422)
                                                                              at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:148)
                                                                              at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:100)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377) 
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                              at com.techweblearn.musicplayer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:116) 
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679) 
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Hi Kunal Puri please show your gradle file here

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove attribute `app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"` from `DrawerLayout` and `CoordinatorLayout`.
2. Add `menu` and `headerLayout` to `NavigationView`.

**Update your `activity_main.xml` as below:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.techweblearn.musicplayer.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

    <include layout="@layout/activity_main_view" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Update your `activity_main_view.xml` as below:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
            style="@style/MyAppTheme"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/black" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/appBar"
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:elevation="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/design_bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="50dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

        <fragment 
            android:name="com.techweblearn.musicplayer.BottomPlayer"
            android:id="@+id/bottom_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Use <include layout="@layout/activity_main_view" />

Comment: there is an error when I add navigationview . otherwise it works fine

Comment: You did not added menu and headerlayout in `NavigationView`. Add and try again...

Comment: Check Line no. 12 >> "InflateException: Binary XML file line #12:". If its start tag of NavigationView, then i think the problem is in design support library.

Comment: What is the version of Design and appcompat-v7 library you used in build.gralde ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the error by adding.

```
app:itemTextColor="#000"
```

in navigationview

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_menu_item"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:itemTextColor="#000"/>
```